# I'm getting this error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'current' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

```
def count_down(start_number):
  while (current > 0):
    print(current)
    current -= 1
  print("Zero!")

count_down(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the 'current' variable before while loop.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you all the information already. You called a variable that does not exist. If you read the whole error message, it should point out the exact variable where the error got triggered.